# How to enable wireless support in Mint Cinnamon 18.2

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, usb, networkmanager, cinnamon

Summary: I have a usb wifi adapter plugged in and recognized by the kernel, but there is no where in the UI to configure it.

- The computer is a 4+ year old HP desktop (i7-4790S CPU, 16GB RAM). More info at the end.
- I plugged in a USB wifi adapter.

  ```
  Trendnet TEW-649UB v1.0R
  (I also have the DLink version of the same device.)
  ```
- The kernel recognized it.

  ```
  [    9.064137] r8712u: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
  [    9.064502] r8712u: register rtl8712_netdev_ops to netdev_ops
  [    9.064505] usb 3-3.4.1: r8712u: USB_SPEED_HIGH with 4 endpoints
  [    9.064771] usb 3-3.4.1: r8712u: Boot from EFUSE: Autoload OK
  [    9.402204] usb 3-3.4.1: r8712u: CustomerID = 0x0000
  [    9.402206] usb 3-3.4.1: r8712u: MAC Address from efuse = 00:14:d1:be:ad:e6
  [    9.402207] usb 3-3.4.1: r8712u: Loading firmware from "rtlwifi/rtl8712u.bin"
  [    9.402293] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8712u
  [    9.405497] r8712u 3-3.4.1:1.0 wlx0014d1beade6: renamed from wlan0
  ```
- the network menu in the system tray doesn't offer a wireless menu
- `nmcli d` does not list the wifi device

  ```
  $ nmcli d
  DEVICE           TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION         
  enx0050b60b7c3c  ethernet  connected    Wired connection 2 
  enp2s0           ethernet  unavailable  --                 
  lo               loopback  unmanaged    --
  ```
- `iwconfig` does

  ```
  enx0050b60b7c3c  no wireless extensions.

  wlx0014d1beade6  unassociated  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
            Mode:Auto  Access Point: Not-Associated   Sensitivity:0/0  
            Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
            Power Management:off
            Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
            Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
            Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

  enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

  lo        no wireless extensions.
  ```
- `rfkill list` does not

  ```
  $ rfkill list
  0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
  ```
- I tried `nmcli r wifi on`

  ```
  $ nmcli r
  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
  enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
  ```

No clue what to do next, or why this is so largely undocumented on the internet.

More detailed information about the machine:

```
$ inxi -Fzx 
System:    Host: harvey Kernel: 4.10.0-37-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.4.6 (Gtk 3.18.9) Distro: Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya
Machine:   System: Hewlett-Packard product: 700-414 v: 1.00
           Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 2AF7 v: 1.04
           Bios: AMI v: 80.20 date: 10/31/2014
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-4790S (-HT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 25542
           clock speeds: max: 4000 MHz 1: 3391 MHz 2: 3200 MHz 3: 3239 MHz
           4: 3302 MHz 5: 3200 MHz 6: 3200 MHz 7: 3200 MHz 8: 3209 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
           bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Desktop
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 C-Media driver: USB Audio usb-ID: 003-006
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.10.0-37-generic
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: e000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 4256.9GB (7.1% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 1000.2GB
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: WDC_WD3003FZEX size: 3000.6GB
           ID-3: /dev/sdc model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 256.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 219G used: 141G (68%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdc2
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 17.08GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-0
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8C mobo: 27.8C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 297 Uptime: 1:36 Memory: 2620.1/15950.6MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Comment: It might help if you showed us the output from `iwconfig`.  And, just for fun, tell us the brand of the Wi-Fi device and the computer. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @G-Man: Is there something that the device has to do or show in iwconfig for Mint to recognize that it needs to enable wireless? wpa_supplicant isn't running on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I needed to restart NetworkManager. It looks like I have to do this for every single boot.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Tails, but the problem is hardware, so may solution may not work for your laptop. I have HP and I need to add module to blacklist like this

`sudo su`

`echo "blacklist acer_wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

You need to restart.

What it does it prevents loading the module acer_wmi responsible for WI-FI driver I whatnot, I don't remember the details. You may need to add different module to blacklist, again research your laptop model.